# Writing HTML code directly from LaTeX?

Tags: tex4ht

At exporting a LaTeX file to HTML via `tex4ht` I have to write some HTML comments to the HTML source. So I would like to write the HTML code in the LaTeX file and let `tex4ht` export it directly. How can I achieve this? Are there some special LaTeX commands to do this?

Comment: I found a solution: \HCode{<!--comment-->} but now I can't export to pdf any more. Is there a way to mask out this tex4ht command for other latex interpreters?

Comment: `\def\HCode#1{}` should disable the command.

Comment: raulix: You should add that (with Caramdir's comment) as an answer so that others who look for this will see that it has an answer.

Comment: you can also use `ifpdf` if you're using `pdf(la)tex` or `ifxetex` if you're using XeTeX.

Answer (score 6):

```
\def\HCode#1{}
...
\begin{document}
...
\HCode{<!--comment-->}
```

It works. tex4ht writes the comment and pdflatex ignores the tag. Fine.

Comment: To get this to work with _both_ `pdflatex` and `htlatex` I needed to use `\ifpdf\def\HCode#1{}\fi`.